# How to use class QueryCriteria?

Tags: corda

someone can help me with this section of code? How to fix it?

[image]

The error is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate one of the known subclasses.
As of Corda is written in Kotlin, I would suggest using it, besides it's more fun also.

Example usage (Kotlin):

```
QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(Vault.StateStatus.ALL)
QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(linearId = listOf(linearId))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the below samples on how QueryCriteria is being used.

https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/e5820c878c0ed783a402ca58623c90a41730c35a/Features/customquery-carinsurance/workflows/src/main/java/net/corda/samples/carinsurance/flows/InsuranceClaimFlow.java#L61

https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/blob/ae0f9cb190cf4c712b77c79a7ed1e79f369aa8ee/Features/customquery-carinsurance/workflows/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/samples/carinsurance/flows/InsuranceClaim.kt#L48

Also make sure you refresh your gradle dependencies.